# Get all documents based on query using Spring MongoOperations

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

My User POJO look like:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

I am able to get single document based on this query:

```
Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("shashi"));
mongoOperations.findOne(searchQuery, User.class);
```

I want to get all the document for this query. Some method call like `mongoOperations.findAll(searchQuery, User.class);`
How I can do this?

Comment: what about `find(searchQuery, User.class);`?

Comment: You can use List like .... List<User> listUser = mongoOperation.findAll(User.class);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Two Option,

**Option 1:**

```
List<User> listUser = mongoOperations.find(searchQuery, User.class);
System.out.println("Number of user = " + listUser.size());
```

**Option 2:**

```
List<User> listUser = mongoOperation.findAll(User.class);
System.out.println("Number of user = " + listUser.size());
```

Note: For further details You can refer [THIS LINK](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example//)